# Using a pointer to an array of structs within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm attempting to use a pointer to an array of structs inside another struct and be able to reference the different structs.  Not sure if i'm doing this correctly as I'm not able to get the code to compile

```
typedef struct profile {
    uint32 age;
    uint32 height;
    uint32 weight;
} profile;

typedef struct {
    uint32 number_of_friends;
    profile (*PROFILES)[];
} records;

// Here's how how i'm attempting to reference the above
uint32 age1;
records record1;
...
age1 = record1.PROFILES[0].age;
```

The error i get is:
error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'records []'

Comment: It seems like you want a [*flexible array member*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flexible-array-members-structure-c/), which can only be used together with dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two problems here. I believe, that you could declare in the struct:

```
profile** PROFILES;
```

or

```
profile* PROFILES[];
```

These have the same effect.

Then where you reference the item, you should take care, that inside the array are profile *-s, so you can refer to them like:

```
record1.PROFILES[0]->age
```

Also consider that there is no space allocated for PROFILES initially, you will have to manually manage the storage underlying that member.